# Hibernate mapping of javax.activation.DataHandler

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping, hbm

I have entity with javax.activation.DataHandler. How can I store it in database using Hiberate xml mappings?

Comment: Serialize it and dump it into blob field. If you give us more context we might be able to provide more detailed help.

Comment: If you are trying to store a webservice attachment and you are using Axis2 you can use org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil in order to manage conversion between DataHandler and other types.